# Android ffmpeg concat two video sound error

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

This is my command
when I am trying to join two video with different resolution with ffmpeg

```
    String[] complexCommand = {
          "ffmpeg","-y","-i",
          paht_1,
          "-i",
          path_2,
           "-filter_complex",
            "[0:v]scale=720:1280,setdar=720/1280[outv0];[1:v]scale=720:1280,setdar=720/1280[outv1];[outv0][outv1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[outv];[0:a][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[outa]",
          "-map",
          "[outv]",
          "-map",
          "[outv]",
            "-r",
            "25",
            "-b",
            "10M",
            "-preset",
            "superfast",
          filePath_video_out
    };
```

and this is my error

```
/mobile-ffmpeg: [NULL @ 0x7c5ce21600] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ffmpeg'
```

/mobile-ffmpeg: ffmpeg: Invalid argument

Comment: Hi, I think you are not supposed to start the array using "ffmpeg", so you can try starting it with "-y"

Comment: @Kartik  i remove ffmpeg and run again Output with label 'outv' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was already used elsewhere

Comment: "[outv]" has been used twice in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should repmove "ffmpeg" at first
then change second outv to outa
same this

```
String[] complexCommand = {
      "-y","-i",
      paht_1,
      "-i",
      path_2,
       "-filter_complex",
        "[0:v]scale=720:1280,setdar=720/1280[outv0];[1:v]scale=720:1280,setdar=720/1280[outv1];[outv0][outv1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[outv];[0:a][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[outa]",
      "-map",
      "[outv]",
      "-map",
      "[outa]",
        "-r",
        "25",
        "-b",
        "10M",
        "-preset",
        "superfast",
      filePath_video_out
};
```